# The explanations of God's love for Hz. Mohammed

Tags: allah

Hz. Mohammed is the only one in humanity who reflects the features and goodness of God too closely to the perfection.
 I don't want to presumptuous but can it be said that God loves Hz. Mohammed because God sees the reflection of himself in Hz. Mohammed? 
Hz. Mohammed is described as surpassing among all humanity. Why this love cannot be defined as a humanely vulnerability?(seeing your reflection, and admiring your reflection)

Comment: May I ask, are you referring to [Gospel of Barnabas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Barnabas) ?

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise be to Allaah

**Firstly**

If you have any reference quoting this reason of Allah's love, than you can say(also let us know of it). Otherwise you can't say. And there is no need to say, i don't see any gain of saying it(given i can't find any reference quoting anything like that)

This being said, now lets **have a look why Allah loves Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)** (Although i believe we have no right to investigate this.)

> “**Allah chooses for Himself whom He pleases**, and guides to Himself
>   those who turn (to Him) [42:13].”

Thats it, he knows best, he has all the powers. He has not said that *I SEE MY PROJECTION IN MUHAMMAD(peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)*. So, no one can declare...

**Secondly**

**If we cannot find any reference for this than this will be a lie** and we should be aware of these ayahs.

> **And who is more unjust than one who invents a lie about Allah** or says,
>   "It has been inspired to me," while nothing has been inspired to him,
>   and one who says, "I will reveal [something] like what Allah
>   revealed." And if you could but see when the wrongdoers are in the
>   overwhelming pangs of death while the angels extend their hands,
>   [saying], "Discharge your souls! Today you will be awarded the
>   punishment of [extreme] humiliation for what you used to say against
>   Allah other than the truth and [that] you were, toward His verses,
>   being arrogant." Al-inam 93

And

> And on the Day of Resurrection you will see **those who lied about Allah**
>   [with] their faces blackened. Is there not in Hell a residence for the
>   arrogant? Zumr-60

Last

> **And who is more unjust than one who invents about Allah** a lie or
>   denies His verses? Indeed, the wrongdoers will not succeed. Al-inam 21

Have a look at [Divine Selection to Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)](http://www.al-islam.org/muhammad-and-his-god-before-bethat-dr-hatem-abu-shahba/divine-selection-muhammad-sa) to understand the selection of Muhammad PBUH.

Have a look at [Ruling on one who tells lies about the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)](https://islamqa.info/en/34725)

**Thirdly**

This action is a **kind of exaggeration** about the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), which the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) warned us against and forbade us to do. He said:

> **“Do not exaggerate about me as the Christians exaggerated about the
>   son of Maryam, for I am no more than His slave, so say, the slave of
>   Allaah and His Messenger.”**
>   (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, Ahaadeeth al-Anbiya’, 3189).

So, we should say only that thing about anything related to Islam about which we have some References from Quran or Hadees.

### Allah Knows Best